# make WPF combobox with checkbox user control with generic class

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I found many solutions but I am struggling with binding generic `class` with `user-control` AND in `ViewModel` .I want to make `ComboBox` with `checkbox`. This `ComboBox` will use generic `class` So I can reuse this `user-control` in entire application.

My question is: How do I bind this generic `class` with my actual `View.xaml` file for `ComboBox`.

This One is my `user-control`

```
<base:CheckedComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <base:BaseCheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding FilterDropDownItemModel.Title}" ToolTip="{Binding FilterDropDownItemModel.ToolTip}" IsChecked="{Binding FilterDropDownItemModel.IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        </base:BaseCheckBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

</base:CheckedComboBox>
```

This one is my generic `class` model

```
public abstract class DropDownModel<T> : BaseModel
{
    private T _mysummary;
    public T MySummary
    {
        get { return _mysummary; }
        set
        {
            _mysummary = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Title
    /// </summary>
    public abstract string Title
    {
        get;
    }

    public abstract string ToolTip
    {
        get;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having? I assume you are binding the ItemSource of the ComboBox to an ObservableCollection of elements, each element derived of type DropDownModel<T>. Could you add context/clarification?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your bindings are all wrong, it should look something like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <base:BaseCheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                       Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=DataContext.FilterDropDownItemModel.Title}" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=DataContext.FilterDropDownItemModel.ToolTip}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=DataContext.FilterDropDownItemModel.IsSelected}">
                </base:BaseCheckBox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Binding with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` and `Path=DataContext.SomeProperty` is fully equivalent to binding without explicitly setting a source and just `Path=SomeProperty`. So the bindings were actually all ok. No idea what makes you think one should explicitly set a binding source.

Comment: @Clemens - this is a control template, so you need the relativesource binding

Comment: Not at all. What makes you think so?